# Android Studio: New gradle build NDK sample app error

Tags: android, android-ndk

I build sample project MoreTeapots from https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk and get errors

> Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleAllDebug]
>   :app:copyArm64-v8aDebugAllMoreTeapotsNativeActivitySharedLibraryGdbServer
>   :app:createArm64-v8aDebugAllMoreTeapotsNativeActivitySharedLibraryGdbsetup
>   :app:compileArm64-v8aDebugAllMoreTeapotsNativeActivitySharedLibraryMoreTeapotsNativeActivityMainC
>   :app:compileArm64-v8aDebugAllMoreTeapotsNativeActivitySharedLibraryMoreTeapotsNativeActivityMainCpp
>   :app:linkArm64-v8aDebugAllMoreTeapotsNativeActivitySharedLibrary
>   :app:stripSymbolsArm64-v8aDebugAllMoreTeapotsNativeActivitySharedLibrary
>   :app:arm64-v8aDebugAllMoreTeapotsNativeActivitySharedLibrary
>   :app:copyArmeabi-v7aDebugAllMoreTeapotsNativeActivitySharedLibraryGdbServer
>   :app:createArmeabi-v7aDebugAllMoreTeapotsNativeActivitySharedLibraryGdbsetup
>   :app:compileArmeabi-v7aDebugAllMoreTeapotsNativeActivitySharedLibraryMoreTeapotsNativeActivityMainC
>   :app:compileArmeabi-v7aDebugAllMoreTeapotsNativeActivitySharedLibraryMoreTeapotsNativeActivityMainCpp
>   :app:linkArmeabi-v7aDebugAllMoreTeapotsNativeActivitySharedLibrary
>   :app:stripSymbolsArmeabi-v7aDebugAllMoreTeapotsNativeActivitySharedLibrary
>   :app:armeabi-v7aDebugAllMoreTeapotsNativeActivitySharedLibrary
>   :app:copyArmeabiDebugAllMoreTeapotsNativeActivitySharedLibraryGdbServer
>   :app:createArmeabiDebugAllMoreTeapotsNativeActivitySharedLibraryGdbsetup
>   :app:compileArmeabiDebugAllMoreTeapotsNativeActivitySharedLibraryMoreTeapotsNativeActivityMainC
>   :app:compileArmeabiDebugAllMoreTeapotsNativeActivitySharedLibraryMoreTeapotsNativeActivityMainCpp
>   :app:linkArmeabiDebugAllMoreTeapotsNativeActivitySharedLibrary
>   :app:stripSymbolsArmeabiDebugAllMoreTeapotsNativeActivitySharedLibrary
>   :app:armeabiDebugAllMoreTeapotsNativeActivitySharedLibrary
>   :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:preAllDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:checkAllDebugManifest
>   :app:prepareAllDebugDependencies
>   :app:compileAllDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileAllDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateAllDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateAllDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:mergeAllDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateAllDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateAllDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:mergeAllDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processAllDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processAllDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateAllDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processAllDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileAllDebugJavaWithJavac
>   Note: C:\Users\Cuong\Downloads\MoreTeapots\app\src\main\java\com\sample\moreteapots\MoreTeapotsNativeActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
>   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>   :app:copyMips64DebugAllMoreTeapotsNativeActivitySharedLibraryGdbServer
>   :app:createMips64DebugAllMoreTeapotsNativeActivitySharedLibraryGdbsetup
>   :app:compileMips64DebugAllMoreTeapotsNativeActivitySharedLibraryMoreTeapotsNativeActivityMainC
>   :app:compileMips64DebugAllMoreTeapotsNativeActivitySharedLibraryMoreTeapotsNativeActivityMainCpp
>   :app:linkMips64DebugAllMoreTeapotsNativeActivitySharedLibrary
>   :app:stripSymbolsMips64DebugAllMoreTeapotsNativeActivitySharedLibrary
>   :app:mips64DebugAllMoreTeapotsNativeActivitySharedLibrary
>   :app:copyMipsDebugAllMoreTeapotsNativeActivitySharedLibraryGdbServer
>   :app:createMipsDebugAllMoreTeapotsNativeActivitySharedLibraryGdbsetup
>   :app:compileMipsDebugAllMoreTeapotsNativeActivitySharedLibraryMoreTeapotsNativeActivityMainC
>   :app:compileMipsDebugAllMoreTeapotsNativeActivitySharedLibraryMoreTeapotsNativeActivityMainCpp
>   :app:linkMipsDebugAllMoreTeapotsNativeActivitySharedLibrary
>   :app:stripSymbolsMipsDebugAllMoreTeapotsNativeActivitySharedLibrary
>   :app:mipsDebugAllMoreTeapotsNativeActivitySharedLibrary
>   :app:copyX86DebugAllMoreTeapotsNativeActivitySharedLibraryGdbServer
>   :app:createX86DebugAllMoreTeapotsNativeActivitySharedLibraryGdbsetup
>   :app:compileX86DebugAllMoreTeapotsNativeActivitySharedLibraryMoreTeapotsNativeActivityMainC
>   :app:compileX86DebugAllMoreTeapotsNativeActivitySharedLibraryMoreTeapotsNativeActivityMainCpp
>   :app:linkX86DebugAllMoreTeapotsNativeActivitySharedLibrary
>   :app:stripSymbolsX86DebugAllMoreTeapotsNativeActivitySharedLibrary
>   :app:x86DebugAllMoreTeapotsNativeActivitySharedLibrary
>   :app:copyX86_64DebugAllMoreTeapotsNativeActivitySharedLibraryGdbServer
>   :app:createX86_64DebugAllMoreTeapotsNativeActivitySharedLibraryGdbsetup
>   :app:compileX86_64DebugAllMoreTeapotsNativeActivitySharedLibraryMoreTeapotsNativeActivityMainC
>   :app:compileX86_64DebugAllMoreTeapotsNativeActivitySharedLibraryMoreTeapotsNativeActivityMainCpp
>   :app:linkX86_64DebugAllMoreTeapotsNativeActivitySharedLibrary
>   :app:stripSymbolsX86_64DebugAllMoreTeapotsNativeActivitySharedLibrary
>   :app:x86_64DebugAllMoreTeapotsNativeActivitySharedLibrary
>   :app:compileAllDebugSources
>   :app:preDexAllDebug
>   :app:dexAllDebug
>   UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>   ...while parsing com/sample/helper/NDKHelper.class
>   UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>   ...while parsing com/sample/moreteapots/BuildConfig.class
>   UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>   ...while parsing com/sample/moreteapots/MoreTeapotsApplication.class
>   UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>   ...while parsing com/sample/moreteapots/MoreTeapotsNativeActivity$1.class
>   UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>   ...while parsing com/sample/moreteapots/MoreTeapotsNativeActivity$2.class
>   UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>   ...while parsing com/sample/moreteapots/MoreTeapotsNativeActivity$3.class
>   UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>   ...while parsing com/sample/moreteapots/MoreTeapotsNativeActivity.class
>   UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>   ...while parsing com/sample/moreteapots/R$attr.class
>   UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>   ...while parsing com/sample/moreteapots/R$drawable.class
>   UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>   ...while parsing com/sample/moreteapots/R$id.class
>   UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>   ...while parsing com/sample/moreteapots/R$layout.class
>   UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>   ...while parsing com/sample/moreteapots/R$string.class
>   UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>   ...while parsing com/sample/moreteapots/R$style.class
>   UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>   ...while parsing com/sample/moreteapots/R.class
>   14 errors; aborting
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexAllDebug'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
>   Information:BUILD FAILED
>   Information:Total time: 4 mins 1.033 secs
>   Information:1 error
>   Information:0 warnings
>   Information:See complete output in console

This is guide http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental.
Its app build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
android {
    compileSdkVersion    = 22
    buildToolsVersion    ="22.0.1"

    defaultConfig.with {
        applicationId    = "com.sample.moreteapots"
        minSdkVersion.apiLevel    = 11
        targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 22

    }
}
android.ndk {
    moduleName ="MoreTeapotsNativeActivity"
    cppFlags   += "-I${file("src/main/jni/cpufeatures")}".toString()
    cppFlags   += "-I${file("src/main/jni/native_app_glue")}".toString()
    cppFlags   += "-I${file("src/main/jni/ndk_helper")}".toString()

    // CFlags is configured in similiar way as cppFlags
    // CFlags    += "-I${file("src/main/jni/native_app_glue")}".toString()

    ldLibs     += ["android", "EGL", "GLESv2","log"]
    stl         = "stlport_static"
}

android.sources {
    main {
        jni {
            source {
                srcDirs 'src/main/jni'
            }
        }
    }
}

android.productFlavors {
    create ("arm7") {
        ndk.abiFilters += "armeabi-v7a"
    }
    create ("arm8") {
        ndk.abiFilters += "arm64-v8a"
    }
    create ("x86-32") {
        ndk.abiFilters += "x86"
    }
    // for detailed abiFilter descriptions, refer to "Supported ABIs" @
    // https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html#sa
    // build one including all productFlavors
    create("all")
}
```

}

Its project build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to      all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
repositories {
   maven {
     url  "http://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools"
   }
   jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.1.0'
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
```

}

Its gradle-wrapper.properties

```
#Wed Apr 10 15:27:10 PDT 2013
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.5-rc-1-bin.zip
```

How can I solve? Thanks.

UPDATE: Solved.  I add

```
    compileOptions.with {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
```

to app build.gradle like

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'
model {
android {
    compileSdkVersion    = 22
    buildToolsVersion    ="22.0.1"

    defaultConfig.with {
        applicationId    = "com.sample.moreteapots"
        minSdkVersion.apiLevel    = 10
        targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 22

    }
}
android.ndk {
    moduleName ="MoreTeapotsNativeActivity"
    cppFlags   += "-I${file("src/main/jni/cpufeatures")}".toString()
    cppFlags   += "-I${file("src/main/jni/native_app_glue")}".toString()
    cppFlags   += "-I${file("src/main/jni/ndk_helper")}".toString()

    // CFlags is configured in similiar way as cppFlags
    // CFlags    += "-I${file("src/main/jni/native_app_glue")}".toString()

    ldLibs     += ["android", "EGL", "GLESv2","log"]
    stl         = "stlport_static"
}

android.sources {
    main {
        jni {
            source {
                srcDirs 'src/main/jni'
            }
        }
    }
}

android.productFlavors {
    create ("arm7") {
        ndk.abiFilters += "armeabi-v7a"
    }
    create ("arm8") {
        ndk.abiFilters += "arm64-v8a"
    }
    create ("x86-32") {
        ndk.abiFilters += "x86"
    }
    // for detailed abiFilter descriptions, refer to "Supported ABIs" @
    // https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html#sa
    // build one including all productFlavors
    create("all")
}
compileOptions.with {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
```

}

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
```

Bug is submitted here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=179660

edit: append it to end of app build.gradle file outside all of sections

Comment: I fixed it with     compileOptions.with {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, the two lines can be added immediately following the 'apply plugin: ...'

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'
sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
```